# MVC4 Templates can be used only with field access

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, lambda

I have a MVC model similar to this

```
public class Model
{
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public int Number {get;set;}
}
```

I receive the error

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

when trying to create a label for the number field, with the model lambda expression stored in a variable.

For example, in my view I have:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name) // Works fine
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Number) // Works fine

@{
    Expression<Func<Offer, object>> nameExpression = model => model.Name;
    Expression<Func<Offer, object>> numberExpression = model => model.Number;
}
@Html.LabelFor(nameExpression) // Works fine
@Html.LabelFor(numberExpression) // Error!
```

I noticed using the debugger that the lambda expression is `model => Convert(model.Number)`, instead of `model => model.Number`, but this only happens to value types from what I can tell, as I have tested with integers (nullable and non-nullable) and `DateTime` objects. 
It seems that the `NodeType` for the lambda expression is `Convert`, for strings is `Member access`.

I know the cause of the error itself, but I don't know what causes the compiler to evaluate `model=>model.Number` to `model => Convert(model.Number)`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a cast to convert `model.Number` from `int` to `object`. You can check that by looking at the expression with the debugger

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Model,System.Object]>(Model $model) {
    (System.Object)$model.Number
}
```

If you want to get the right expression you have to use `Expression<Func<Model, int>>`

```
Expression<Func<Model, int>> numberExpression = model => model.Number;
```

This expression is translated to

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Model,System.Int32]>(Model $model) {
    $model.Number
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I didn't notice this, it's a silly mistake, but I got it to work now.